# how to set up mysql2 with rails2

Tags: ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-2, mysql2, compatibility

I've upgraded my app to Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.9.2, and I've been having all sorts of strange issues with MySQL. At first, I've used the `ruby-mysql` gem (2.9.3), until I realized it had some encoding problems, and the consensus seems to be to upgrade to using `mysql2` gem.

So, I've removed the old `ruby-mysql` adapter and installed `mysql2`, and also included it in my application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

In addition, I've updated `database.yml` with `adapter: mysql2`. From what I've read on the documentation this should be it, but I keep getting a crash when trying to boot my app:

```
$ ./script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require': no such file to load -- mysql (MissingSourceFile)
from ..vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
from ..vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from ..vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from ..config/environment.rb:81:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

I thought this should be a drop in replacement for mysql adapter in Rails. Anything I need to configure differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to remove the original `mysql` gem from your `Gemfile`.